# php session variable value dont update in same page

Tags: php, session, variables

i have a session variable named 'logerr' if that variables equals to 0 user has not logged or log was ok... but if user / pswd was not found.. variable changes to 1 and the main page display "login error
like this
index.php

---

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['openclose']) && $_SESSION['openclose']=='1') {
        header("location:index2.php");
        exit();     
    }
?>
<?php 
   if(isset($_SESSION['logerr'])) {
    $errlog=$_SESSION['logerr'];
   } else {
    $errlog=0;   
   }
?>
bla
bla
 <?php
 if($errlog==1) {
  ?>
    <h5 class="redfont">Error de Login!!</h5>
       <?php
  }
    ?>                 
<h2>write user & pswd</h2>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="f1.php">
```

bla
bla

f1.php

---

```
ob_start();
bla
bla

if($count==1){  <-- means if the user or paswd was found
session_start();
    $_SESSION['logerr']=0;
    $_SESSION['openclose'] = '1';
bla
bla
    header("location:index2.php");
    exit();

} else {
    $_SESSION['logerr']=1;
    header("location:index.php");
    exit();
}
?>
```

the thing is the login error phrase never appears and error variable allways is zero..

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your session start to the line before your if statement. In your case the session will only start if you've not got an error, so you cannot set the error variable.

```
    ob_start();
// bla bla
session_start(); // moved //

if($count==1){  <-- means if the user or paswd was found
$_SESSION['logerr']=0;
$_SESSION['openclose'] = '1';
bla
bla
header("location:index2.php");
exit();

} else {
$_SESSION['logerr']=1;
header("location:index.php");
exit();
}
?>
```